# If condition is working at the same time with else

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, button

i have added a database item to my form in visual studio c#, i have a form for the table i have in database i copied the "save button"s code to a random Button1, i tryed to give it a constrain like if "name" textbox is empty show a massage and dont put the info to the database like on the bottom, it changes the label but my else command which i coppied from save button also works. How can i stop it from working. I dont want to save the textboxes to database with that if condition is valid:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (middle_NameTextBox = "";)
        {
            label1.Text = "id is empty";
        }
        else
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.customerBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.database1DataSet);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Should `middle_NameTextBox = "";` be `middle_NameTextBox == ""`....? I prefer `string.IsNullOrEmpty(middle_NameTextBox)`

Comment: middle_NameTextBox == ""

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code to observe what it's *actually* doing?

Comment: That code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @juharr You're correct. The title doesn't make sense even if it could compile some how.

Comment: [Debugging in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx) also how can if condition be working at the same time the else is working when the if condition is obviously wrong. there is a difference between `Assignment = and Comparison check ==`

Comment: `show a massage`..? you mean show a `Message` don't you..?

Comment: you want to fix this easily..then first use the debugger your code is incorrect in the first if condition need to check if it's `==` also use the debugger and tell us what the value of middle_NameTextBox.Text` is
furthermore what if there is a space before the Middle name then you need to check the following 
`if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(middle_NameTextBox.Text.Trim()))`

Comment: you need to also show all relevant code.. you are making a simple process more difficult than it needs to be.. you need to understand how to check values in C# using a `if` statement. this can't be this difficult

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If middle_NameTextBox is textbox then you have to check for the text inside the textbox like this :

```
if(middle_NameTextBox.Text==""){}
```

Comment: what is this..? can you explain this non answer..??

Answer (score 0):

Try this because your code doen not work.

```
if(middle_NameTextBox == "")
{
// Do something 
}
```

In c# we compare 
 String type we only use == or !=

for Integers and float types we use
<=  >=  as well as  == or !=

Comment: Except that `<=` and `>=` will not work with `string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid all of this by using `string.Equals`:

```
if (middle_NameTextBox.Equals(string.Empty)) //...
```

Comment: personally I think that `.Equals` method should be used to compare objects vs values `==` but that's just my take

Comment: @MethodMan -- except `string.Equals` has its own overrides for dealing with string equality, e.g. [String.Equals(String, StringComparison)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which are very useful.

Comment: it doesn't change the label, it saves the data to database.

Comment: @AlpayAydıngüler -- I really don't know what you mean.